# jQuery / Selecionar o item dentro de um array, referente a posição do loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loop

Boa tarde amigos, estou com dificuldades em encontrar uma solução lógica para resolver meu problema em um loop (for)

Dentro de uma tabela, temos uma informação de preço na tag: `<p class="preco-plano">R$44</p>` e criei uma tag em branco:`<p class="milesQnt"></p>`para a quantidade de milhas no caso. A quantidade de milhas é de 1 para 1, ou seja 1 real equivale uma milha, portanto na `<tr>`onde o valor for 420 reais, a quantidade de milhas deve ser 420 reais.

Vejam o código abaixo:

```js
 $(function(){
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    let milesToWrite = $('.milesNumber');
                    let tableRow = $('tr');
                    for(i=0; i<tableRow.length; i++) {
                        let milesNumber = $('tableRow[i] preco-plano').split('$')[1];
                        milesToWrite.textContent = milesNumber + "milhas";
                    }
                });
            });
```

```html
<table class="tabela resultados">
            <tr>
                <th>Preço</th>
                <th>Milhas</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p class="preco-plano">R$44</p></td>
                <td>
                    <span><p class="milesQnt"></p></span>
                    <span><input type="button" value="AVANÇAR"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p class="preco-plano">R$140</p></td>
                <td>
                    <span><p class="milesQnt"></p></span>
                    <span><input type="button" value="AVANÇAR"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p class="preco-plano">R$420</p></td>
                <td>
                    <span><p class="milesQnt"></p></span>
                    <span><input type="button" value="AVANÇAR"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script src="skin/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Eu fiz um laço de repetição que deve passar por todas as `<tr>` da tabela e alterar o valor da tag de milhas em branco pelo número que há na tag de preço... porém ao tentar acessar o preço do plano dentro da tableRow[i] (que é a tr que o loop está no momento) da erro. eu compreendo que minha semântica está errada, porém ao tentar acessar o "preco-plano" sem definir a posição do loop, ele altera apenas a primeira tag e não as demais.

Preciso de sugestões!

eu poderia chamar primeiro a variável e depois usar o jquery para selecionar a query do preço? por exemplo criar uma variável: `let x = $('.preco-plano')` e então chamar desta forma dentro do loop `tableRow[i].x` ?

Eu deveria usar o `forEach` invés do `for` para o loop?

minha lógica está errada, deveria fazer o loop direto pela tag à ser substituída, no caso: `milesQnt` invés de `<tr>`?

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Acabei de ver que esqueci do seletor de query antes do nome da classe "$('tableRow[i] .preco-plano')... de qualquer forma não rodou, para na mesma parte do código... sei que eu usar a variável ai dentro está incorreto já =\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É só fazer um `.each` pela classe `.preco-plano` e alterar o texto da classe `.milesQnt` que tem em comum a mesma linha `tr`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".tabela .preco-plano").each(function(){

      var milesToWrite = $(this).text().split('$')[1];
      $(this).closest("tr").find(".milesQnt").text(milesToWrite);

   });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tabela resultados">
   <tr>
       <th>Preço</th>
       <th>Milhas</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><p class="preco-plano">R$44</p></td>
       <td>
           <span><p class="milesQnt"></p></span>
           <span><input type="button" value="AVANÇAR"></span>
       </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><p class="preco-plano">R$140</p></td>
       <td>
           <span><p class="milesQnt"></p></span>
           <span><input type="button" value="AVANÇAR"></span>
       </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><p class="preco-plano">R$420</p></td>
       <td>
           <span><p class="milesQnt"></p></span>
           <span><input type="button" value="AVANÇAR"></span>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Veja que foi preciso muito menos código do que o que você tentou. Também havia alguns erros no seu código, como por exemplo:

```
$('tableRow[i] preco-plano').split('$')[1];
```

Você tentou fazer split no elemento, e não no texto.

Outra coisa é que você está repetindo o evento `ready`:

Isso `$(function(){` e isso `$(document).ready(function(){` são a mesma coisa.

Comment: pode crer! eu teria que ter usado ".textContent" e ai sim poderia manipular o texto! Muito obrigado pela ajuda e pela dica no final tbm!

Comment: sim muito menos código! essa é a ideia do jQuery correto? fazer mais com menos... enfim, muito obrigado!